# Hyperlink add in OTRS Ticket?

Tags: mysql, otrs, ticket-system, itil

I need a hyperlink in OTRS Ticket.

How can i add a hyperlink for a particular ticket in its right pane under ticket information of OTRS.

This is needed to link with other system.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the link by modifying the template in `Kernel/Output/HTML/Templates/Standard/AgentTicketZoom/TicketInformation.tt`

But please read the documentation on creating your own 'themes' for how to modify them while keeping your system upgradeable:
http://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/stable/en/html/themes.html

Also, if the link is using data in a Dynamic Field you can do it in the Dynamic Field configuration and you don't need to modify the template at all, see the "Show link" option here:
http://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/stable/en/html/dynamicfields.html#dynamicfields-configuration-text

And if all the tickets you want the link to appear in have customer records, you can also use this config option and modify it: http://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/stable/en/html/ConfigReference_Framework.html#ConfigReference_Framework:Frontend::Customer:Frontend::CustomerUser::Item_2-Google